# MySQL Workbench接続できない

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

（拙い質問で恐縮ですみません)

Macユーザーです。
ドットインストールの動画を見ながらターミナル上でMySQLを利用できるようにしました。
Visual Studio for Macを用いて.NET COREアプリケーションのプロジェクトを作成し、c#で開発しようとしていますが、MySQLに接続できません。

はじめはNugetでMySQLの追加のみをしていましたが上手くいかないためMySQL Workbenchもダウンロードしましたが、そちらでも接続できません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

すべてのホストで接続できる権限のユーザーも作りましたがやはり上手くいきません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

またbind-addressが設定されていないことも確認済みです。
'127.0.0.1'や自身のIPアドレスを設定した状態でもWorkbenchの接続を試しましたがそれもだめでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうしたらよいかわかりません。

Comment: workbenchでアクセスしているユーザ名は `dbuser` ですか？エラーメッセージは `root` とありますがどうでしょうか？

Comment: キャプチャ以外にもrootでもhost"%"で登録してあります。それでも上手くいきません。。